# What does "trust proxy" actually do in express.js, and do I need to use it?

Tags: node.js, nginx, express, proxy

I am writing an express app that sits behind an nginx server.  I was reading through express's documentation and it mentioned the 'trust proxy' setting. All it says is

> trust proxy Enables reverse proxy support, disabled by default

I read the little article here that explains Secure Sessions in Node with nginx.

http://blog.nikmartin.com/2013/07/secure-sessions-in-nodejs-with-nginx.html

So I am curious.  Does setting 'trust proxy' to true only matter when using HTTPS?  Currently my app is just HTTP between the client and nginx.  If I set it to true now, are there any side-effects/repercussions I need to be aware of? Is there any point to setting it true now?

Comment: I had to set that to get my cookies working on heroku, don't really get why

Answer (score 85, accepted):

This is explained in detail in the [express behind the proxies guide](http://expressjs.com/guide/behind-proxies.html)

> By enabling the "trust proxy" setting via app.enable('trust proxy'), Express will have knowledge that it's sitting behind a proxy and that the X-Forwarded-* header fields may be trusted, which otherwise may be easily spoofed.
>
> Enabling this setting has several subtle effects. The first of which is that X-Forwarded-Proto may be set by the reverse proxy to tell the app that it is https or simply http. This value is reflected by req.protocol.
>
> The second change this makes is the req.ip and req.ips values will be populated with X-Forwarded-For's list of addresses.

Comment: Yea but that literally doesnt explain anything, when you do set it to true, if you set it to 1 hop, how do you know how many hops away the nginx server is, if you set it to ip address, whose ip are we setting and how do you find this ip, if you set multiple ips, what are these ip addresses, copy pasting the documentation is so much easier when you dont explain anything, when do you set it to 127.0.0.1, does that work on ec2, should you set it to loopback address on a live ec2 server

Comment: Can someone answer @PirateApp questions? I'm curious to know what to do when serving from a subnet.

Comment: so the point here of the word "trust" is that you are telling express that you know what set of machines your node/express process is sitting behind.

in my case, I have my nginx reverse proxy serving ssl, and files, and upstreaming to express for the app. so I can set my `trust proxy` to "loopback".

/1

Comment: All that we are saying is that from xyz location we know that headers havent been tampered with, which has "subtle implications" as described in the docs. One example is "https only" cookies, which wouldnt work in express if it was running as http server behind nginx ssl, with trust proxy express can tell its actually being served as https from the X-Forwarded-Proto header, which you need to know hasnt been tampered with

/2

Answer (score 45):

Annotated code to explain use of trust proxy

```
    var express = require('express');

    var app = express();

    // Set the ip-address of your trusted reverse proxy server such as 
    // haproxy or Apache mod proxy or nginx configured as proxy or others.
    // The proxy server should insert the ip address of the remote client
    // through request header 'X-Forwarded-For' as
    // 'X-Forwarded-For: some.client.ip.address'
    // Insertion of the forward header is an option on most proxy software
    app.set('trust proxy', '127.0.0.1');


    app.get('/test', function(req, res){
      var ip = req.ip; // trust proxy sets ip to the remote client (not to the ip of the last reverse proxy server)
      if (ip.substr(0,7) == '::ffff:') { // fix for if you have both ipv4 and ipv6
        ip = ip.substr(7);
      }
      // req.ip and req.protocol are now set to ip and protocol of the client, not the ip and protocol of the reverse proxy server
      // req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] is not changed
      // req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] contains more than 1 forwarder when
      // there are more forwarders between the client and nodejs.
      // Forwarders can also be spoofed by the client, but 
      // app.set('trust proxy') selects the correct client ip from the list
      // if the nodejs server is called directly, bypassing the trusted proxies,
      // then 'trust proxy' ignores x-forwarded-for headers and
      // sets req.ip to the remote client ip address

      res.json({"ip": ip, "protocol": req.protocol, "headers": req.headers['x-forwarded-for']});
    });

// in this example the reverse proxy is expected to forward to port 3110
var port = 3110;
app.listen(port);
// test through proxy: http://yourproxyserver/test, req.ip should be your client ip
// test direct connection: http://yournodeserver:3110/test, req.ip should be your client ip even if you insert bogus x-forwarded-for request headers
console.log('Listening at http://localhost:' + port);
```

Answer (score 20):

**TLDR** : Application setting **trust proxy** simply intended to be used if the express application is behind a proxy. Enabling this when there's a proxy helps to resolve following properties through well known headers (mainly X-Forwarded-For, X-Forwarded-Proto)

- **[req.ips](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.ips)**
- **[req.hostname](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.hostname)**
- **[req.protocol](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.protocol)**

**More details**

I ended up here when searching for what **trust proxy** really does with regards to **express-session**. None of the answers helped me.

Default value - false (disabled)

IMO the best documentation is at [Application Settings](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.set)

> **trust proxy**
>
> Indicates the app is behind a front-facing proxy, and to use the
> X-Forwarded-* headers to determine the connection and the IP address
> of the client. NOTE: X-Forwarded-* headers are easily spoofed and the
> detected IP addresses are unreliable.
>
> When enabled, Express attempts to determine the IP address of the
> client connected through the front-facing proxy, or series of proxies.
> The `req.ips` property, then contains an array of IP addresses the
> client is connected through. To enable it, use the values described in
> the trust proxy options table.
>
> The `trust proxy` setting is implemented using the proxy-addr package.
> For more information, see its documentation.
>
> NOTE: Sub-apps will inherit the value of this setting, even though it
> has a default value.

p.s - If you are trying to see how this helps with express-session, then enabling trust proxy is required to get the correct value for **req.secure**

Answer (score 4):

Since `nginx` is mentioned in the question, note that in your nginx conf (e.g. /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default) you also need to explicitly set the header variable in order to pass it through to express:

```
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
  location /api/ {
    proxy_pass               "http://127.0.0.1:8000";
  }
```

That's the bare minimum required, however something like this below will be faster by using zone of persistent connections to your upstream server(s):

```
upstream backendAPI {
    zone       upstreamZone     64K;
    server     127.0.0.1:8000   weight=1  max_fails=2 fail_timeout=4s;
    keepalive  2;
}

proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
location /api/ {
    proxy_pass           http://backendAPI;
    proxy_http_version   1.1;
    proxy_set_header     "Connection" "";
}
```

Then you can enable the user's (supposed) IP address in the express server's request object by switching on "trust proxy":

```
const app = express();
app.set("trust proxy", true); // populate req.ip
// you can also name the proxy servers ips for increased security:
//   app.set("trust proxy", "127.0.0.1"); 
//   app.set("trust proxy", "192.168.3.3"); 

app.get("/api/myIP", (req, res) => {
    const ip = req.ip;
    return res.json({ ip });
});
app.listen(8000);
```

Comment: Great answer showing a full config!