# Keycloak Node.js Adapter not working behind corporate proxy

Tags: javascript, node.js, keycloak, keycloak-connect

Unable to get `https://www.npmjs.com/package/keycloak-connect` to work with proxy. I am able to access the Keycloak server with the same proxy from the browser and from curl, though.

The only promising thing that I have tried was this:

```
app.set('trust proxy', 'loopback');
```

... and it didn't work.

I am able to connect through keycloak-connect if I am using it on my own WiFi (no proxy). The error that I get when using the proxy is:

```
Could not obtain grant code: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 108.128.***.168:443
```

`108.128.***.168` was the IP of the Keycloak server.

I can't verify whether there is a configuration that would allow me to use keycloak-connect with proxy.

Attaching few lines of the code that relate to keycloak:

```js
const Keycloak = require('keycloak-connect');
const memoryStore = new session.MemoryStore();

const keycloakConfig = {
  clientId: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
  'auth-server-url': process.env.SERVER_URL,
  'confidential-port': 0,
  'policy-enforcer': {},
  'ssl-required': 'external',
  'verify-token-audience': true,
  realm: process.env.REALM,
  credentials: {
    'secret': process.env.CLIENT_SECRET
  },
  realmPublicKey: process.env.REALM_PUBLIC_KEY
};

const keycloak = new Keycloak({
  store: memoryStore
}, keycloakConfig);

const MongoStore = mongoSessionStore(session);

const sess = {
  name: 'ssg-next.sid',
  secret: sessionSecret,
  store: new MongoStore({
    mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection,
    ttl: 14 * 24 * 60 * 60
  }),
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  cookie: {
    httpOnly: true,
    maxAge: 14 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
  }
};

if (!dev) {
  server.set('trust proxy', 'loopback'); // trust first proxy
  sess.cookie.secure = true; // serve secure cookies
}

server.use(keycloak.middleware({
  logout: '/logout'
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to `app.set("trust proxy")` but `app.enable("trust proxy")`.

Stumbled into this myself and [saw a SO question about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23413401/what-does-trust-proxy-actually-do-in-express-js-and-do-i-need-to-use-it/42765157#:%7E:text=app.set(%27trust%20proxy%27%2C%20%27127.0.0.1%27)%3B).
I currently sail smooth without anything else behind "trust proxy" as in the example - running my apps behind an Ingress Controller but this essentially resolved my protocol problems with Keycloak.